# Why the binary representation is different from python compiler than what we know on paper?

Tags: python, binary

Bitwise NOT is the first complement, for example:

- `x = 1` (binary: 0001)
- `~x = -2` (binary: 1110)

Hence, my question is why -2 in binary is (-0b10) as for the python compiler?

We know that 1110 represents (14) for unsigned integer and (-2) for signed integer.

Comment: `-` is a unary operator there, it's `-(0b10)`. Python integers are arbitrary precision, they have (approximately) infinitely many digits, so a twos complement representation doesn't really make sense.

Comment: `bin(-2) = '-0b10'`. I suppose this is rather the external representation that the internal representation. `type(bin(-2)) is <class 'str'>`

Comment: @Ronald: That's because the `bin()` function returns an string value.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? You've cited two different binary number schemes (signed and unsigned), so it should be clear that there is more than one representation of a number. What exactly is your confusion about ``-0b10``? ``0b10`` is 2, so ``-0b10`` is literally - 2. Note that the internal representation of numbers is an implementation detail - ``-0b10`` is merely a human readable representation.

Comment: my confusion is why the result in the compiler is not aligned with 1110? in other world why the representation is like this instead (-0b10)?  I am looking for an internal insight into what happened in the compiler to give the result in that way

Comment: @martineau: that was exactly my point: it seems that the string representation is in the question.

Comment: @MaherBouidani Again, why *should* it be ``1110``? You yourself have given at one example in which ``1110`` is not -2.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi exactly then basically we agree, my question is why the representation is that way (-0b10)? what is the internal work inside the compiler to give the result in that way?

Answer (score 3):

Two's complement inherently depends on the size of a number. For example, -2 on signed 4-bit is `1110` but on signed 8-bit is `1111 1110`.

Python's integer type is arbitrary precision. That means there is no well-defined leading bit to indicate negative sign or well-defined length of the two's complement. A two's complement would be `1... 1110`, where `...` is an infinite repetition of `1`.

As such, Python's integer are displayed as a *separate sign* (nothing or `-`) and the *absolute number*. Thus, `-2` becomes `-` and `0b10` – i.e. `-` `2`. Similarly, `-5` becomes `-` and `0b101` – i.e. `-` `5`.

Note that this representation is merely the standard representation to be human-readable. It is not necessarily the internal representation, which is implementation defined.

Comment: Thanks man but still It is not the answer for my question. If I may re-phrase the question: What is the mathematical/scientific model in which python represents the -2 as -0b10?

If I ask you to give me -3 representation as for python compiler without looking into the compiler result,  you would need then a math rule/model/method to do it, what is this method?

Comment: @MaherBouidani I don't see how this is not answered already. ``-0b10`` is literally ``-`` and ``0b10`` – i.e. ``-`` ``2``. Similarly, ``-3`` becomes ``-`` ``0b11`` – i.e. ``-`` ``3``.

Comment: okay I know that but this is not what happens internally inside the compiler, I mean there is a decoupling between the internal representation and the external one that we see on the console output. what is the rule that governs this decoupling?

Comment: As explicitly mentioned, the internal representation is implementation defined. That means there *is no rule* that "governs this decoupling", since otherwise the specification of the human readable representation would dictate the internal representation – making it not implementation defined anymore.