# Confusion with 1's compliment binary representation

Tags: python, binary, bit, complement, ones-complement

I was trying to learn binary representation of negative numbers. I tried to output 12 and ~12 in binary.

```
print(~12)
```

Output:

```
-13
```

This was the 1's complement of 12.

But my doubt is that **binary 12 is 1100** and **-13 (1's complement of 12) is 0011** but **3 is also 0011** in binary. This was very confusing for me.

How -13 and 3 can have same binary values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the binary representation is different from python compiler than what we know on paper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332193/why-the-binary-representation-is-different-from-python-compiler-than-what-we-kno)

Comment: 12 in binary is all zeroes except for the 4-bit and the 8-bit. `-13` in binary is *all ones* except for those bits. It's not `0011`. It's `11...110011`.

Comment: You are ignoring signed/unsigned and width. 12 is 1100 in *unsigned four bit* binary. There is no two complement in this representation, and 0011 is unambiguously 3. You need *signed five bit* binary to represent both 12 and its two-complement, which are 01100 and 10011, respectively. In this representation, 00011 is unambiguously 3.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - Sorry for the silly question.  Is there a rule of thumb (per se), outside of the given context, to identify `10011` as the signed five bit binary for ~12, rather than 19?

Comment: Note that ``~`` is not the 1's complement. It is defined as ``~x == -(x+1)``, which matches arbitrary-precision 2's complement.

Comment: @S3DEV No. Binary – as a sequence of bits – can mean literally anything. There is no guarantee that ``10011`` is even a number, it could just as well be the ASCII glyph ``CR`` or the first half of the UTF-8 glyph ``Ꮢ``. Going further, you technically must know byte and bit endianness – ``10011`` might be ``25`` in unsigned integer little bit endianness.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: -13 and 3 do not have the same binary values. The confusion arises from ignoring explicit sign and padding/width.

---

Python integers behave as *unsigned* arbitrary width binary numbers, with a *separate* sign bit. There is no general, unambiguous binary representation for *signed* numbers.

For example, 12 is the number `...1100` and the sign `+`, and -12 is the same number `...1100` but the sign `-`. Notably, the `...` may be arbitrary many leading digits – `1100`, `01100`, `001100` and so on are all the same number. This 0-padding allows to treat small and large numbers alike, e.g. the at-least 4-digit 12 `...1100` can be aligned with the at-least 5-digit 16 `...10000`.

This means there cannot be a specific leading sign bit, since each position could be preceded by another `0`. Instead, the sign bit arbitrarily precedes the number: `0...1100` or `+...1100` is 12, and `1...1100` or `-...1100` is -12. This is visible in the canonical bitwise representation of numbers separating the sign and absolute value.

```py
>>> bin(12)
0b1100
>>> bin(-12)
-0b1100
```

As such, the 4-digit bitwise complement of 12 is `-0011`, while 3 is `+0011`.